# How to load a detail page using FlyoutMenu without App Shell from a button programmatically in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, flyout

I use Flyout menu in Xamarin.Forms without App Shell and I need to load a detail page from existing already created pages using a simple button (programmatically) from another details page. How can I implement this? Is there any mechanism for this action?

Answer (score 0):

Of course -- did you even try to find an example in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage)?

Assuming your application main page is the flyout page (which it should be) then you can simply call:

```
((FlyoutPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail = myExistingPage
```

You can also use the detail page as its own navigation stack if it wrapped in a `NavigationPage` in which case you would do:

```
await ((FlyoutPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(myExistingPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a detail page from existing already created pages using a simple button (programmatically) from another details page, you could use the code below.

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FlyoutPage1 flyoutPage1 = new FlyoutPage1();

        var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Page3));
        page.Title = "Page3";

        flyoutPage1.Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
    
        Application.Current.MainPage = flyoutPage1;


    }
```

For more details about the FlyoutPage, you could check the link below. [Lower AppShell Flyout Below Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110096/lower-appshell-flyout-below-navigation-bar/69113405#69113405)